# Add columns to dataframe set to initial value based on list dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have a vector let's call it x:

```
x <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
```

and I let's say I also have a dataframe df, what is the dplyr way to create columns for each value in the vector and intialize them at asome value (eg. 0).  I know this would be simple in base R as I could do the following:

```
df[,x] <- 0
```

However I was curious about the dplyr way.
Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  You say it would be simple in base R - can you provide what your base R code and expected output would look like for a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: If I have a df and a vector x.  I could do this:
df[,x] <- 0

Comment: was wondering what the dply equivalent would be?

Comment: @ben You can edit that into your question so it's clearer, maybe also providing a sample df just to make it easier to write corresponding answers.

Comment: @ben890, could you explain what situation suggests it should be done in `dplyr` vice the simple base-R method you provided? It's lost on me, and unless there is something substantial to gain, the elegance of `df[,x] <- 0` is hard to beat.

Comment: I was just curious.

Answer (score 1):

The `[<-` function can be used in dplyr type calls, although I don't think it is any more elegant. I'm assigning to 1 rather than 0.

```
features <- 
structure(list(f1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("blue", "geeen"
), class = "factor"), f2 = c(0, 0), a = c(0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")

features %>% `[<-`(TRUE, c("a","b","c"), 1)
     f1 f2 a b c
1  blue  0 1 1 1
2 geeen  0 1 1 1
```

I did discover that numeric assignments to factor columns get handled a bit differently with the dplyr coding. The base `[<-` assignment will coerce to numeric, while the combined use of "%>%" with "[<-" witll result in 's of factor class:

```
str( features %>% `[<-`(TRUE, "f1", 0) )
#--------------
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ f1: Factor w/ 2 levels "blue","geeen": NA NA
 $ f2: num  0 0
 $ a : num  0 0
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c(0, 0)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Comment: Huh, this worked the first time I ran it but then failed in a new R session, even with the base R version `` `[<-`(features, TRUE, c("a","b","c"), 1) `` (I couldn't figure out the backticks for comments here...) yielding "Error in `*tmp*`[[j]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2"

Comment: However, ``features %>% `[<-`(, c("a","b","c"), 1)`` works fine.

Comment: I'm seeing the same. So the dplyr/magrittr method actually "works". Wonder what would happen with `assign`? Also there doesn't seem to be a `[<<-`. The dplyr `%<>%` would provide that facility. (Backticks are not something I've been able to do properly in comments either.) Wait, did they remove `%<>%` ? No, it's in magrittr.

Comment: Within magrittr, there is a `[[<-` (simply aliased as inset2) and that's also the only place `%<>%` appears. I'm not sure why the magrittr stuff like `%<>%` isn't also loaded into dplyr.

Comment: "%<>%" does rather violate the functional paradigm, although so does "[<-" when you try (and fail) to use it in functional form. It must be a "primitive".